# Fetch last record in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want fetch last record using hibernate criteria

Can u help me?

Comment: with no more informations, I'm afraid we can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by hibernate criteria in mySQL?
hibernate criteria is used in java to retrieve persistant class objects.

in my SQL you can run following query

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM yourtable ORDER BY xyz DESC LIMIT 1
```